# Mocha test suite errorring out when attempting to connect to API

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gulp, mocha.js

I'm running my test suite using `mocha`, via `gulp-jsx-coverage` and `gulp-mocha`. All my tests run and pass/fail as expected. However, some of my modules being tested make HTTP requests to my API via the `superagent` library.

When in development, I'm also running my API at `localhost:3000` alongside my client-side app, and so that is the URL my client-side tests are attempting to access. When testing, though, the API is usually not running. This results in the following error any time a request gets through:

```
Error in plugin 'gulp-mocha'
Message:
    connect ECONNREFUSED
Details:
    code: ECONNREFUSED
    errno: ECONNREFUSED
    syscall: connect
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
Stack:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:983:19)
```

I've tried stubbing all of the methods on the `superagent` (aliased as `request`) library in a global helper, like so:

```
function httpStub() {
  return {
    withCredentials: () => {
      return { end: () => {} };
    }
  };
};

beforeEach(function() {
  global.sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();

  global.getStub = global.sandbox.stub(request, 'get', httpStub);
  global.putStub = global.sandbox.stub(request, 'put', httpStub);
  global.patchStub = global.sandbox.stub(request, 'patch', httpStub);
  global.postStub = global.sandbox.stub(request, 'post', httpStub);
  global.delStub = global.sandbox.stub(request, 'del', httpStub);
});

afterEach(function() {
  global.sandbox.restore();
});
```

But for some reason, when some tests are encountered the methods aren't stubbed and so I reach the `ECONNREFUSED` error. I've triple checked, and no where am I restoring the sandbox or any stubs.

Is there either a way to fix the problem I'm running into, or a cleaner solution for this overall?

Comment: Is the behavior deterministic? You are writing that the problems occur for 'some tests' - is it always the same set of tests that fail or a certain test can pass in one test-run and fail in the other?

Comment: @TomasKulich it doesn't fail on the same test every time, but it does fail within a certain subset of tests. This is just because these are the tests whose actions would eventually result in calls to the API. If I run a single test file that previously error'd out, it would pass. It seems to only occur when running the entire suite, presumably due to the `request` methods somehow becoming unstubbed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might might be caused by not doing asynchronous stuff properly in your test. Imagine following example:

```
it('is BAD asynchronous test', () => {
  do_something()
  do_something_else()
  return do_something_async(/* callback */ () => {
    problematic_call()
  })
})
```

When Mocha finds such a test it executes (synchronously) `do_something`, `do_something_else` and `do_something_async`. In that moment, from Mochas perspective the test is over, Mocha executes afterEach() for it (what is bad, the `problematic_call` is still yet to be called!) and (what is even worse), it start running the next test!

Now, obviously, running tests (and beforeEach and afterEach) in a parallel manner can lead to really strange and unpredictable results, so it's no surprise something got wrong (probably afterEach was called in the middle of some test which lead to unstubbing the environment)

What to do with it:

Always signal to Mocha, when your test ends. This can be done either by returning a Promise object, or, by calling `done` callback:

```
it('is BAD asynchronous test', (done) => {
  do_something()
  do_something_else()
  return do_something_async(/* callback */ () => {
    problematic_call()
    done()
  })
})
```

https://mochajs.org/

This way Mocha 'knows' when your test ends and only then it runs the next test.

Comment: If this really is a problem of yours, you might still have hard times debugging it - omg omg where the hell is the callback / promise I'm not waiting for. If this is the case I'll write few useful tricks you can use.

Comment: It looks like you were right. I was aware of the `done` callback for async tests and thought I was using it everywhere necessary, but it turned out some of my other tests needed to be async as well. Fixing the handful of broken tests also meant I could remove those ugly global stubs on `request` and only stub in the relevant tests. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, I'm glad it helped. Also, remember that quite fine option for the async function is to return a Promise object (you have to properly chain the Promises, though).

Answer (score 1):

`request` has already been required by your application, so it doesn't matter whether or not your stub it in your tests.

You need to use something like [`rewire`](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) and replace the `request` required by your application with your stubbed version.

Something like this should help

```
var request = require('superagent'),
    rewire = require('rewire'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    application = rewire('your-app'),
    rewiredRequest;

function httpStub() {
    return {
        withCredentials: () => {
            return { end: () => {} };
        }
    };
};

beforeEach(function() {
    var requestStub = {
        get: httpStub,
        put: httpStub,
        patch: httpStub,
        post: httpStub,
        del: httpStub
    };

    // rewiredRequest is a function that will revert the rewiring
    rewiredRequest = application.__set__({
        request: requestStub
    });
});

afterEach(function() {
  rewiredRequest();
});
```